# Content overshot screen despite putting ContentPlaceHolder & <div> as width :100%

Tags: c#, css

I'm creating a webapp that is able to view on the phone while it fits nicely to screen. I have so far tried it by changing the CSS of the respective webapp. Initially it fits nicely like this below making any selection to the dropdownlistbox.

[image]

However, making a selection that is filled with images/text, the layout change drastically.

[image]

This is my CSS code where i re-size the parent layout, which is ContentPlaceHolder as shown below

```
#ContentPlaceHolder
{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  left:0px;
}
```

I have inserted this contentplaceholder css attribute in the masterpage via this tag

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder"></div>
```

The layout of the all the details below is categorize as headerbody.

```
#headerbody
{
  margin-top:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0%;
  margin: 0px;
  width:100%;


}
```

The 3 textbox shown in the picture also has a width:100% attribute in it as shown below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOR" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="80px" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

Prior to my knowledge, as long as the parent layout which is contentplaceholder is 100%, shouldn't the picture extends beyond 100%? It works perfectly on my desktop but not on my opera emulator. Would appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on this.

Regards.

***UPDATE***
By reducing the size i have fixed for the images, it fix nicely to my mobile emulator. However, the picture is a little too small. Is it possible all 5 picture to fit nicely to screen?

Comment: the images width might be fixed?

Comment: I fixed my images as 250x250. However, the contentplaceholder is fixed at 100% width. Shouldn't it exceed beyond that? It works perfectly fine for my desktop though.

Comment: For the UPDATE: Yes there are ways to resize your picture. And for the previous comment , check through some Developer tool that none of the parent elements for contentplaceholder div the width is fixed or any min-width or max-width parameter is set

Comment: Try Giving Width for html

`html {
width:960px;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
#ContentPlaceHolder
{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: no difference. the picture still extends beyond my slideshow and navbar

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, try using:

```
<div style="width:80%;overflow-y: visible">
<ul style="width:100%">
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

overflow-y: visible; will add horizontal scroll bar to the container div.